# Splash screen is having slight jarring effect on load in react native

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

On opening of the app splash screen image loads as stretched, were as when image is loads from launch_screen it moves to center

Instead of `FrameLayout` tried using `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` with all possible scale types, same for background_splash.xml tried all possible combilnations with scale type like

**launch_screen.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**background_splash.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Expected result is : In both cases i.e on opening of app and later the images loaded from background_splash.xml, launch_screen.xml should look same

Answer (score 0):

Splash is one thing if you want to make it happen perfectly, try making it natively.

Add the splash images in the Android Mdpi, Hdpi, XHDPI and other Android image folders found in `android/app/src/main/res` and add the images. Then give the image it's respective image path. 
Also there is a slight white buffer when the react native bridge starts which compile JS code to native codes which produces a miniframed white screen for few micro seconds to control that [use this library.](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

Also try giving the splash image some resize modes and resize method of `contain` and styling of `flex:1` with respective image ratio.

This will make your splash look perfect. Also the dimensions of splash should be 1242 pixels wide and  2436 pixels tall -- this is the width of the iPhone 8 Plus (the widest iPhone) and the height of the iPhone X (the tallest iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml , replace

@drawable/background_splash

with
@drawable/background_splash

Solved the issue for me.